# What was George McFly's and Biff's jobs in the original timeline?

Tags: back-to-the-future

At the beginning of *Back to the Future* we see a scene, which we later see a parallel of in 1955) where Biff asks George whether he has completed his work yet so he can get it typed up.  I'm just wondering **what was George McFly's and Biff's jobs in the original timeline?**

Comment: I snooped around and managed to find a copy of the novelization.  It is no help.  It says Biff is a security guard, and there is no reference to him and George working together.

Comment: @WadCheber [the script](http://www.scifiscripts.com/scripts/back_to_the_future_original_draft.html) says the same thing: Biff is supposed to be a security guard at a golf course and there's no reference to George needing to have done Biff's work - they really diverged from the script a lot here!

Comment: @N_Soong : This one's looking to be tough!  There are several different scripts actually.  The actual shooting script just mentions the "reports" that need to be done but doesn't say what they are for, and mentions that Biff is "mid-management" but doesn't say what he manages.

Comment: I expect they are TPS Reports...

Comment: @DanielRoseman - ...and I could set the building on fire...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## Mid-management, nothing more specific.

After about two months of trying to find an answer, I'm forced to conclude that no specific occupation had been assigned to George and Biff with regards to the first film.

Things I did:

- looked at multiple versions of the script
- read / listened to interviews with Robert Zemeckis (director / writer), Bob Gale (writer), Steven Spielberg (producer), Tom Wilson (actor, Biff), and Crispin Glover (actor, George)
- read the novelization by George Gipe (I don't recommend this)
- asked Tom Wilson directly (but didn't receive a response, unfortunately)

In the various materials I consulted, the "reports" that George and Biff were working on were never described.  It can be assumed they are mid-management (responsible for the reports, but accountable to a higher authority), but nothing more can be said.

Comment: Greatly appreciate the effort you went to for this!